# $5$-adic expansion

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

Given $x = 2+1\cdot5+3\cdot5^2 +2\cdot5^3 +\ldots ∈ \mathbb{Z_5}$, find $\frac{1}{x}$, expressing it similarly as a $5$-adic expansion. (First 4 digits only).

I'm new to p-adic numbers and was struggling to do this question. Any hints?

Answer (score 2):

If you're only interested in the $4$ first "digits", then it means that you are working in $\mathbb{Z}/5^4\mathbb{Z}$. So what you want is the inverse of $332$ in $\mathbb{Z}/625\mathbb{Z}$ (if my mental calculation is correct).

In general, remember that truncating a $p$-adic expansion is just reducing from $\mathbb{Z}_p$ to $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I only can deduce the first $4$ digits , because I am only given $4$ for $x$.

Comment: Yes, precisely. If you put $f: \mathbb{Z}_5\to \mathbb{Z}/5^4\mathbb{Z}$ the reduction map, then you are not given $x$ but $f(x)$, so you can only get the inverse of $f(x)$ in $\mathbb{Z}/5^4\mathbb{Z}$ and not the inverse of $x$ in $\mathbb{Z}_5$.

Comment: $x=332$ or $.2132$ or $.2312$? Then how do I find it's inverse?

Comment: You’re always dealing with the rightmost digit of your divisor $2312;$, and if the digit down below that you want to match is $d$, then you need an $x$ such that $2x\equiv d\pmod5$. In other words, $x=d\cdot2^{-1}$. I hope you know that $2^{-1}=3$, because $2\cdot3\equiv1\pmod5$.

Answer (score 2):

It’s really easiest to do this by writing in standard $5$-ary notation, as you did in elementary school, and as I explained in depth in a [recent post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1684634/5-adic-expansion-of-%E2%88%922/1684946#1684946). Your number then is written as $2312;$ — the rightmost digit is the units digit, the next to the left is the $5$’s digit, etc.

Division is easily described on a blackboard, but the published word is comparatively unsatisfactory; I’ll try nonetheless. You write the dividend $1$ on the left, but include sufficiently many zero-digits, so that’ll be $0001;$, and on the right you write your divisor, thus:
$$
\begin{matrix}
0&0&0&1;&\Big|&2&3&1&2;
\end{matrix}
$$
Now you look at your rightmost digits, and ask what number mod $5$ gives $1$ when multiplied by $2$, in other words, you want the mod-$5$ reciprocal of $2$. That’s $3$, of course, so that’s the first digit of your quotient. You write that above, and multiply that $3$, now as an ordinary integer, times your divisor $2312;$, and put the product $2441$ below the $0001;\,$. (To do the multiplication, you may find that it helps to prepare yourself with a $5$-by-$5$ multiplication table, so that you know that $3\times3=14$, for instance. So far, you have this:
$$
\begin{matrix}
&&&3;\\
0&0&0&1;&\Big|&2&3&1&2;\\
2&4&4&1;
\end{matrix}
$$
Next step is to subtract, right? This is long division, don’t forget. When you subtract $2441;$ from $0001;$, you get $2010;$, but I’ll omit that rightmost zero, so that the next few steps look like this:
$$
\begin{matrix}
&&3&3;\\
0&0&0&1;&\Big|&2&3&1&2;\\
2&4&4&1;\\
2&0&1\\
4&4&1
\end{matrix}
$$
and I’ll let you finish it out. You should get the quotient $4333;$

Comment: I am also interested in this question. How did you get the second $3$ in the quotient and why do you get $ 4 4 1$

Comment: I have $210$ next then $41$ then $30$ then $3$ and finally $0$. But I'm still unsure on how to get the quotients.

Comment: @Polp, the line “$201$” arises from subtraction; the last digit is $1$, so you again need a number $x$ such that $2x\equiv1\pmod5$. That’s $x=3$. I hope this answers both your questions.

Comment: What do we multiply the $3$ by? Is it the opposite of multiplication. So for the first quotient we multiply $3$ by $2312$. Next is it $312$ and then $31$ and finally $3$? I have $441$ then $210$ then $41$ then $30$ but $4*3=2 mod 5$?